# Consult on the submiting format of PNAS

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission

I am now learning about the submitting process of PNAS. The instruction says that the authors are encouraged to submit the article in a single PDF file. However, I am wondering how could I create this PDF file. Do I have to transform a word into a PDF, or I should get this PDF file created by the Article Sizing Tool, which is a tool provided by PNAS to estimate the total length of the article. Moreover,could I just submit the article by using a word?

Answer (score 1):

The [author instructions](http://www.pnascentral.org/cgi-bin/main.plex?form_type=do_help&file_nm=sm_qty) state that "A single PDF file is acceptable for initial submissions of all research articles except Contributed papers". Further down it is also stated that "Publication-ready file formats include Word or LaTeX."

This means that depending on what type of manuscript you are submitting, different rules may apply. Word and LaTeX (the latter must be accompanied by a PDF file) are fine but for a few forms like their "Express Submissions" require a single pdf to be submitted initially. Only of the manuscript passes the initial stage will it be required to provide editable files.

You should generate the PDF from your Word document or LaTeX class files according to the instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will check it.  What puzzles me is that why do the jouranl provide a tool to create a PDF file which combine all materials together. If I don't use this created PDF, will the journal reject me?

Comment: @caliant, as long as you follow the instructions to submit one PDF, it shouldn't matter what tool you use to create it. The important point is that you submit *one* file in the PDF format. The PNAS tool is provided for the convenience of folks who cannot otherwise create the PDF file from their source materials.